# How can I attach the SSL authenticated certificate for my SQL Server 2014 if it is not on domain controller

Tags: sql-server, encryption, ssl, windows-server, certificate

We have Microsoft Azure with Windows Server 2012 R2 in Cloud Computer and window Server is Standalone it is not come under domain controller. We want to add SSL authentication.

1. SQL Server is not showing the certificate because certificate "Full
   Qualifier Name" is not containing matching name

So we put "SmartServerSystem" computer name get the CSR. During the validation we got error

2. Data in "Common name" field is invalid. because it not a domain
   name.
3. We tried to change the name app.SmartServerSystem.com then
       name is not change because it is not come under the domain
       controller

My question is how can I attach the SSL authenticated certificate for my SQL Server 2014? If it is not in Domain controller.